# Bootstrap 4 class for "text-align: left"

Tags: bootstrap-4, text-align

I can use `style` attribute for use `text-align` but I want to use bootstrap class.

What's the equivalent of 
`style="text-align:left;"` in bootstrap 4?

Comment: This type of question is [simply answered by reading the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

Comment: use 'text-left' class, it is a bootstrap class for left align text.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer is,

```
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
```

For other alignments,

```
<p class="text-left">Left aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
```

Alignment in other devices,

```
<p class="text-sm-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized SM (small) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-md-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized MD (medium) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-lg-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized LG (large) or wider.</p>
<p class="text-xl-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider.</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In bootstrap you can use class `text-left` for `style="text-align:left;"`, for more information check out this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/)

Comment: problem is that text-left is always superceded by the parent div in BootStrap, so you must specify the style directly in all cases involving bootstrap containers. Oversight on their part.